# Clang ast-dump missing several statements?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to do some analysis on Linux kernel source code using clang AST representation. But I found some statements in source are missing in clang AST.
The first picture is a snippet of the kernel source code. As we can see, there are 7 functions in the IfStmt.
[Linux Source snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C7HB.png)

The second picture shows the result of `clang -Xclang -ast-dump ~/mm/mmap.c`, but there are only four functions. Three functions and four statements in yellow boxes are missing in AST representation. [result of clang AST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0aDu.png)

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04, with clang9.0.0. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Did you check the result of preprocessing?

Comment: I think there are no functions and statements missing in the result of preprocessing. I checked the preprocessing result with `clang -E`, and the function is almost the same as the source except the removal of comments.